# How to make an inspector window like the Button class? Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So I am currrently writing a very broad script, that I want to be able to just drag and drop whatever method I want to call from it. How does one go about making an inspector window to do so, like the button script?

[image]

I have a public method in the script that I am writing, that I would like to be able to do exactly what the button class does in the inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `UnityEvent` as `public` or `[SerializeField]`. Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AnyMethodClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public delegate void EventListener();
    public event EventListener MyEvent;
    public System.Action MyAction;
    public UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent MyUnityEvent;
}
```

[image]

Note that `event` does very similar thing to `UnityEvent` but is not exposed in the Inspector.

`delegate` and `Action` from C# are types that can specify one method or a list of methods, and they are also not visible in the Inspector as `event`.

The recommeneded way in Unity is to use `UnityEvent` instead of `event`.